# Red5 recorded stream playing issue with Flash Player 17.0.0.169

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, red5, red5-recorder

I am experiencing this problem, where once a stream is recorded with red5 and I try to play it, the stream plays in a fast-forward manner.

You can reproduce this issue on this link
http://www.technogumbo.com/tutorials/Recording-Decent-Quality-Video-And-Audio-With-Flash-and-Red5/

This happens only with Flash Player 17.0.0.169, not on the older versions.

A quick help will be appreciated.

[UPDATE]

I have recorded following stream with red5 v1.0.5 from a swf running at top of flash 17.0.0.169;

http://misc-items.s3.amazonaws.com/elance/sportseed/stream_0018D224-79E3-1AA7-E208-D08C2B3DE7DF.flv

The stream plays fine when the flash player version is < 17 but when it is 17.0.0.169 it plays in a fast-forward way.

Try opening following link on flash player version 17.0.0.169 and on the older versions of flash player, you will notice the issue yourself;

http://misc-items.s3.amazonaws.com/elance/sportseed/html5_video.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recent version of Flash Player has addressed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is caused by publishers not having sufficient bandwidth during recording. There are server adjustments to help keep everything in-order, but they don't cover every case. Try your recordings in another player like VLC to ensure they are not damaged. Test your installation with these config properties:

```
# drop audio packets when queue is almost full, to disable this, set to 0 
rtmp.executor.queue_size_to_drop_audio_packets=0
# increase from default of 120 if slow connections are present 
fileconsumer.queue.size=2048
```

These go in the red5/conf/red5.properties file.

Comment: The recorded stream only have issue when playing in flash player 17.0.0.169. Otherwise the play fine in older flash versions and vlc.

Comment: The problem persists even after I have made suggested changes. I encounter the problem even when the red5 server is on my local machine.

Comment: I have recorded this stream with red5 v1.0.5 from a swf running at top of flash 17.0.0.169; [link](http://misc-items.s3.amazonaws.com/elance/sportseed/stream_0018D224-79E3-1AA7-E208-D08C2B3DE7DF.flv), this plays fine when the flash player version is < 17 but when it is 17.0.0.169 it plays in a fast-forward way. You can try it on this link [link](http://misc-items.s3.amazonaws.com/elance/sportseed/html5_video.html)

Comment: This is the first I've heard of a FP 17 issue; I'd prefer to see more cases or an issue report before I dig into this.